# Dynamic search query using JpaRepository

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a "Product" entity with "id" "productName" and "price"

I implement a server side pagination and filter with angular ng-table.

My client send a json like

```
"{"page":1,"sort":"DESC","orderBy":"productName","filter":{"productName":"test","price":300}}"
```

but could be like that

```
"{"page":1,"sort":"","orderBy":"","filter":{}}"
```

How can I implement this kind of dynamic query wit jpaRepository

```
query = "select * FROM products WHERE 1=1 "
for (Map.Entry<String, String> filter : filters.entrySet()) {
    String key = filter.getKey();
    String value = filter.getValue();
    query+= "AND " + " LIKE %" + value + "% "
}

if(!orderBy.isEmpty())
{
  query.="ORDER BY " + orderBy + " ";
}
etc.
```

my
**IProductRepository.java**

```
public interface IProduitRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    @Query("select p from Produit p where p.price = :x")
    public Page<Product> customFindByPrice(@Param("x") String name,Pageable p);

    public Page<Product> findByPrice(double price, Pageable p);
}
```

So how can I implement my dynamic searsh query with JpaRepository ?

I know about [predicate](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) but I don't really understand how to use them in my case

Answer (score 2):

You could use Elastic Search as fastest search engine.
And for the formation of query I would strongly suggest using SerchQueryParser: https://www.npmjs.com/package/search-query-parser.

Comment: Sorry I can't accept your response, i want one repository for each Entity which implement JpaRepository and allow to create dynamic request as I ask. ElasticSearch seems good but the answer is specific and the response is not. I don't want multiple repository just for my product Class and i want to keep JpaRepository implementation.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic queries you can make your Spring Data JPA repositories extend `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` in addition to extending `CrudRepository`.  This will give you access to methods such as `findOne(Predicate)` and `findAll(Predicate)` on the repositories.

There isn't extensive official documentation on using QueryDSL with Spring Data modules but there are online tutorials such as [this one](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-five-querydsl/) that provide a decent introduction to using QueryDSL with Spring Data JPA.

Alternatively, if you have very simple dynamic queries or if you want to stay within the JPA realm, you can extend your repositories from `JpaSpecificationExecutor` to gain access to methods such as `findOne(Specification)` and `findAll(Specification)` on the repositories.